# Downcast an inherited class to base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let say i have a base class

```
class baseClass
{  }
```

And another class that inherit from that `baseClass`

```
class foo : baseClass
{  }
```

I tryed to cast it back directly `(baseClass)foo` but the compiler say it cannot be done.

Is there a way from `foo` to get only the `baseClass`?

Comment: It can be done. What code did you try ?

Comment: Can you show the actual complete piece of code where "the compiler says it cannot be done" - and hopefully the actual error message too?

Comment: foo f = new foo() 
baseClass b = f;

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here? What is your requirement ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo` **is** a `baseClass` you don't need any casting. And your code should work without any problems:

```
var foo = new foo();
baseClass x = (baseClass) foo;
```

Comment: omg I fell so stupid atm... just tryed directly and it work...zzzzz accepting answer in a few minutes

Comment: @im_a_noob remember - you don't need this casting. Simply assign `baseClass x = foo`

Comment: yeah just tryed with out any casting and it work. I tryed this `baseClass x = (baseClass) foo;` type of explicit cast and it didn't work. I think as @Serge said, this is because both class aren't in the same namespace

Comment: @im_a_noob if it is namespace problem, then your code will not compile without any casting. You just can't use `foo` or `baseClass` if you didn't add namespace reference. Compiler will complain that `The type or namespace name 'baseClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 2):

If you derive a class **A** from class **B** you can always refer to **A** as if it were **B**. Of course this is not true in the revese case. In general you can always refer down the chain of inherited classes.

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler complain on such a thing, it could just mean you have several baseClass defined in several Namespace and you're actually not referencing the right baseClass.

Check your Namespaces it should solve your bug.

Comment: I think this partially the answer, my base class is in another namespace but i tryed to cast it with full path (ex: `(System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs)foo` ) but it didn't worked

Comment: Make sure you're referencing the right baseClass on your foo classe (it's a class and your variable name?) declaration.

Comment: yeah I was referencing the right base class, and no it wasn't my class and a variable name. Just using class name in exemple

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example with different Namespaces

```
namespace BaseNameSpace
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace TestNameSpace.Class
{

    public class TestClass : BaseClass
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Use :

```
TestClass test1  = new TestClass();
BaseClass b = test1;
```

Ensure that there is the correct using :

```
using BaseNameSpace;
using TestNameSpace.Class;
```